# Get notifications when UIAlertView is displayed or dismissed, thats shown from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I have a `UIAlertView` that  being presented by another class(long story), I want to get notified when the `UIAlertView` is dismissed in **current** view.

Similar to this question [How to observe when a UIAlertView is displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599590/how-to-observe-when-a-uialertview-is-displayed)

The accepted answer: Say that class A creates the UIAlert and class B needs to observe it. Class A defines a notification. Class B registers for that notification. When Class A opens the alert it post the notification and class B will see it automatically sounds good,

Has anyone done something similar who could expand on this

Comment: Using notifications is certainly a good solution.

Comment: Try it and come back if you have problems (then show code).

Comment: @Wain, if i knew how to do that I wouldn't be asking the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own class `MyAlertView` that shows the alert normally but posts notifications for events like showing the view and being dismissed.

Just create a class with a simple interface like `-showAlertWithTitle:`

```
// Class interface
- (void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString*)string
{
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:string message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}

// UIAlertViewDelegate methods
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyAlertViewDidPresentAlert" object:nil];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyAlertViewDidDismissAlert" object:nil];
}
```

Something like that.

In the first viewController you would need this:

```
// First viewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didPresentAlert:) name:@"MyAlertViewDidPresentAlert" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didDismissAlert:) name:@"MyAlertViewDidDismissAlert" object:nil];
}

- (void)didPresentAlert:(NSNotification*)notification
{...}

- (void)didDismissAlert:(NSNotification*)notification
{...}
```

Comment: How would the event be received in the other view? ie reading back `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyAlertViewDidPresentAlert" object:nil];`

Comment: Got you now, thanks for that, just what I was after!